# Stored procedure to script database objects to file?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'd like to write a stored procedure in SQL 2005 to script all my database objects to a file.  The only problem is...I have no idea how to do it.  Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try something like this,

First of all creating a new store procedure in your SQL server, like this.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ListObjectsToFile
AS
BEGIN
 select * from sysobjects;
END
GO
```

And then call it from the Command Line, indicating your complete connection string and the path/name of the output file

> C:\>sqlcmd -S
>   yourServer\yourSQLServerInstance -U yourUser -P yourUserPassword -q
>   ListObjectsToFile -o C:\list.txt

Hope that helps,

Santi! :)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply!  Forgive the noobish question, but what would be the best way to automate the call to the command line?  Batch file?  Thanks.

Comment: Also, is yourSQLServerInstance my database name?  Thanks!

Comment: No, the SQL Server Instance is "optional", and is only required if you have installed SQL Server twice or more on the same machine. When doing so, you must give a name to the second and other instances you install. So, if SQL Server is installed only once, just forget the "\yourSQLServerInstance" part

Comment: You'll want to add a `-d yourDatabaseName` parameter to the command line to select a particular database, otherwise the default database associated with the login will be used (normally this is `master`).

Comment: And where ever possible, use a trusted connection (`-E` parameter) instead of the username/password combination. This lessens the chance of someone knowing the password if someone else reads the batch file.

Answer (score 2):

I know your question says that you want a Stored Procedure to do the job done, but if you want an other solutions, I would be using [SMO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx) in VB.NET. When accessing database objects with the .NET objects, they all got a "Script()" function which returns the SQL to use to recreate the object. [A table for instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.table_members.aspx).

Hope this might help

Comment: +1, I have yet to see a tsql approach to script out a complete runnable table script, which includes all possible table definition items: PK, FK, index, defaults, check constraint, computed columns, etc..

Answer (score 0):

Try DBSourceTools. (http://dbsourcetools.codeplex.com)
Its open source, and specifically designed to script an entire database 
- tables, views, procs and data to disk, and then re-create that database through a deployment target.