# Need sql script to generate creation scripts for each object (views, tables, SP's, indexes, users)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need a Transact-SQL script to generate the creation scripts for each object (views, tables, SP's, indexes, users) in the database. Each creation script will be saved in a .sql file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at [`Sql Server Scripting`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178078(v=sql.105).aspx) in SSMS.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421601/stored-procedure-to-script-database-objects-to-file

Answer (score 2):

Go to your Sql Server Management Studio

Right Click your Database from where you want to create the scripts and follow the path shown in the screen shot.

[image]

Comment: What I need is a script, not by clicking some options in the SQL enterprise manager

Comment: something like this:

select all objects to iterate each one of them
(
   create a script to generate again the current object in the iteration list.

   then, save the script in a .sql file in the hard disk
)


that's it, thanks in advance